# How to use $q to get a promise from a $broastcast in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise, broadcast, q

Right now my controller code looks like this:

```
$scope.spAPI.load(id).then(function(result){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  if(result !== undefined){
    deferred.resolve($rootScope.$broadcast("onSpLoaded", result));
  }
  return deferred.promise;
}).then(function(success){

      $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({ ... });


});
```

I want the modal instance to be opened AFTER the broadcasts are processed. Is there a way to do this?

Update: I was thinking about this problem backwards. I meant to do the broadcast after the modal instance, anyway, nevermind.

PS: I did have problems with the modalinstance.opened callback though, I had to hack my way around it. I am still struggling to use $q correctly, my code has been getting messier.

Comment: Your code looks fine, it should do what you want. because `$broadcast()` is a synchronous operation, all the event handlers should be called when `$broadcast()` returns

Answer (score 1):

Your controller code looks fine, it should work as expected, you just don't need the deferred object in your first `then()`:

```
$scope.spAPI.load(id).then(function(result){

  if(result !== undefined){
    $rootScope.$broadcast("onSpLoaded", result);
  }

}).then(function(success){

  $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({ ... });


});
```

The reason here is because `$broadcast()` is synchronous operation, all the event handlers will have been called when `$broadcast()` returns; and the function in 2nd `then()` will only be called after the function in the first `then()` returns, so `$modal.open()` will be called after all event handlers.

<kbd>[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/glUX1SmzplvPMSfsrcQp)</kbd>

#### Update:

You know that `$scope.modalInstance.opened` is a promise which will be resolved when the modal gets shown, so you can try the following to achieve what you want:

```
$scope.spAPI.load(id).then(function(result){
    $scope.modalInstance = $modal.open({ ... });

    $scope.modalInstance.opened.then(function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("onSpLoaded", result));
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated my question. I was just not thinking about my problem the right way. Still learning that $q thing. :)

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Nbe4af6pWIGtys1Jt8Fz?p=preview - tried but seems not to work with promises