# Subscribe an event on child scope and return callback in broadcast\emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, publish-subscribe

I came after reading [@toddmotto](https://twitter.com/intent/follow?screen_name=toddmotto) excellent [post](https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19498009/1509853), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15596131/1509853) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21688018/1509853) answers, the [api](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) And now I have ctrl structur like this

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl as parent" class="ng-scope">
  <div ng-controller="SiblingOneCtrl as sib1" class="ng-scope"></div>
  <div ng-controller="SiblingTwoCtrl as sib2" class="ng-scope"></div>
  <div class="btn btn-primary"
       ng-click="parent.events.saveDreaft()">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
       <span>Save</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

&&

```
define(['app'], function (app) {    
   app.controller("ParentCtrl", ['$scope', '$q',  function ($scope, $q) {
        var parent= this;  
        parent.data = {};         
        parent.events = {                
            saveDreaft: function() {
                $scope.$broadcast('saveDreaft');
                //return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                //    try {
                //        var ee = $scope.$broadcast('saveDreaft');
                //        if (ee)
                //            resolve();
                //    } catch (ex) {
                //        reject(ex);
                //    }
                //});
            }
        };
   }]);
});

//=======

define(['app'], function (app) {
  app.controller("SiblingOneCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', '$q', 
   function ($scope, $http, $q) {

        var sib1 = this;            
        sib1.events = {
           saveSib1Form: function () {
                return $http.post('..', ..)
                            .then(function (res) {..})
                            .catch(function (ex) {..});
            }
        };

        var unbind = $scope.$on('saveDreaft', function (event, data) {
            sib1.events.saveSib1Form();
            //return $q.when(sib1.events.saveSib1Form)
            //         .then(function(res) {
            //              event.targetScope.callbackRes = { 
            //                res: res, 
            //                flag: true 
            //              };
            //          })
            //          .catch(..);
         });

        $scope.$on('$destroy', unbind);
    }]);
});
```

when client click save from the parent scope we want the child run his own save method and then send some callback to the publisher, like [`jQuery.Callbacks()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) that he finish maybe `$q` promise.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$emit` to implement a *callback-like* function in your child scope:

```
sib1.events.saveSib1Form();
$scope.$emit('saveComplete', args);
```

And register for the `$emit` event in your parent scope:

```
$scope.$on('saveComplete', function(event, args) {
    //your callback code
})
```